# Angular cli v1.0.4 - When I change code in components, it doesn't reflect on browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Angular cli - When i change code in components, Application refreshes but changes are not there. When i stop and run ng serve again then i see changes that i made.

Node v6.10.2
npm v4.6.1
OS - win8.1

package.json

```
"dependencies": {

    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.26",
    "bootstrap": "next",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
"devDependencies": {

    "@angular/cli": "1.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
}
```

Comment: `ng serve --hmr`

Comment: @Slava Utesinov, Thank you. It works.

Answer (score 0):

ng serve --hmr by Slava Utesinov